# R shiny with mathjax conditional cases

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements, mathjax

Hi I am aware that you can have inline equations in an R-shiny app using the `withMathJax` function, but from what I have seen it is simple math equations that you can use like at the Rshiny examples [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/mathjax.html). I was wondering if any one new how to add conditional cases, as you would in latex with the following code

```
f(n) =
\begin{cases}
n/2,  & \text{if $n$ is even} \\
3n+1, & \text{if $n$ is odd}
\end{cases}
```

which would produce the below, cheers

[image: conditional output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think thats what you want or?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- {fluidPage(
  title = 'MathJax Examples',
  withMathJax(),
  uiOutput('ex4')
  )}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$ex4 <- renderUI({
    withMathJax(
      helpText('$$f(n)=\\begin{cases}
               n/2,  & \\text{if $n$ is even} \\\\
               3n+1, & \\text{if $n$ is odd}
               \\end{cases}\\!$$'))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score -2):

[how to acheive conditional output based on tab selection in shiny app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50629365/how-to-acheive-conditional-output-based-on-tab-selection-in-shiny-app/50632317?noredirect=1#comment88281070_50632317)

I think the above link can give you a good info of how to write conditional cases. It also has a link which has a proper tutorial of applying Conditional cases.I hope it will be of help to you.

Comment: I think the question is about conditional cases in MathJax style, not conditionalPanels of shiny.

Comment: It was about a little help to the question as it is mentioned in the tag conditional cases, its not always about the ezact ans rather somethime ref. aslo work Mr SeGa 6

Comment: I think the question was quite clear and nicely illustrated. The tag conditional may be a bit confusing though.